# Django above version 2.1.5: how to set urls.py to allow get method to work?

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I want to reuse the same template "createchapter.html".
In other words, I wan to link to "createchapter/?step=1.html", "createchapter/?step=2.html","createchapter/?step=3.html".

I am using Django 2.1.5, so there are few resources or Q&A to learn.

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
(.....)
    url(r'^createbook/$',viewsSentence.createbook),
    url(r'^createchapter/<int:step>$',viewsSentence.createchapter),

]
```

In views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
    @csrf_protect
def createchapter(request,path):


   if request is not None:
      if request.GET.get('step') is None:
         context1 = {
            'books': book.objects.order_by('titleOrigin'),
            'step': 1,
         }

         #useless: return HttpResponse('/?step=1',context1)
         redirect("createchapter.html",context1,step=1)

      elif request.GET.get('step') == 2:
         context2 = {
            'step': 2,
         }
         redirect("createchapter.html", context2,step=2)
```

In createchapter.html

```
{% if step == 1 %}
      <form>
          {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
           <i class="fas fa-forward"></i>
          <label for="select-books">Step 1: select a book</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="select-books">
                {% for book in books %}
                <option value="{{ book.id }}">{{ book.titleOrigin }}</option>
                {% endfor %}

          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"><a id="createchapter-step2">Step 2</a></i>
        </div>
    {% elif step == 2%}
    <div class="form-group">
           <i class="fas fa-forward"></i>
          <label>Step 2: set numbers of chapters</label>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Here's how I call the second page(I use ajax):

```
 $("#createchapter-step2").click(function(){

        var selectedbookId = $("#select-books option:selected").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/createchapter/?step=2',
            type:'get',
            data:{
                'selectedbookId':selectedbookId,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $( "#csrfmiddlewaretoken" ).val(),
            },
        });
    });
```

The error message is :

> ```
>     Page not found (404)
>     Request Method:   GET
>     Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/createchapter/?step=1/
> ```

Comment: step=1 wouldn't work as per your code. But just leave it as http://127.0.0.1:8000/createchapter/1/

Comment: @VineethSai, I've also tried JPG 's method. Thank you. In my urls.py, I write "^createchapter/<int:step>/$", and the error message is "The current path, createchapter/1/, didn't match any of these.". The debug says that my Request URL is 127.0.0.1:8000/createchapter/1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you are doing is using [url querystring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/createchapter/?step=1`. You don't need to define it in the urls(the **step** part). So it should be like this:

```
url(r'^createchapter/$',viewsSentence.createchapter),
```

Then to get the url querystring parameters, you can try like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


@csrf_exempt
@csrf_protect
def createchapter(request):
   step = request.GET.get('step')  # it will fetch the step from url

   if step == "2":
     context = {
        'step': 2,
     }

   else:
     context = {
        'books': book.objects.all().order_by('titleOrigin'),
        'step': 1,
     }

   return render(request, "createchapter.html",context)
```

Comment: I've applied your method. Thank you very much. The first page succeeded, while the second page didn't. The python terminal catches the request.GET.get('step') correctly as "2", but the render didn't  make effect. The terminal shows "[10/Jan/2019 15:19:02] "GET /createchapter/?step=2&selectedbookId=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1901
". The browser remains silence.

Comment: Sorry I made a small mistake. The value of `step` is a string, so it should be matched with `"2"`. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you; I actually noticed that and changed it to a string before you commented  here but the browser still remained silence. I also edited my question by adding something about the .js file.

Comment: Maybe instead of doing an ajax request, you can try like this:

`window.location = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + "/createchapter/?step=2";`

Answer (score 1):

You have entered the wrong URL, It should be as **`http://127.0.0.1:8000/createchapter/1/`**

Comment: I've also tried your method. Thank you. In my urls.py, I write "^createchapter/<int:step>/$", and the error message is "The current path, createchapter/1/, didn't match any of these.".  The debug says that my Request URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/createchapter/1/ .